# Batch: Variable assign and compare

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple Batch that gets my Wifi IP and adds specific routes of public IPs to the WiFi. My WiFi has the prefix of 10.240 (wip). The problem I am having seems more to do with syntax in my code.

I have the following:

```
@echo off
set wip=10.240
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('route print ^| find " 0.0.0.0"') do (

    @echo on
    REM set localIp=%%i
    set ip=%%i
    set xwip=%ip:~0,6%

    IF "%wip%" == "%xwip%" (

        echo My IP:  %ip%
        route ADD 95.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 %ip%
        route ADD 54.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 %ip%
        goto :break
)

:break
```

I turned the echo on to debug and noticed the following:

```
set ip=10.240.1.103
set xwip=10.113
IF "10.240" == "10.113" (
echo My IP:  10.113.1.83
route ADD 95.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.113.1.83
route ADD 54.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.113.1.83
```

If I set the variable **%%i** to **ip**, why is it using the previous iteration's value?

My route table which I'm concerned with is the following:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.113.1.1      10.113.1.83     10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.240.1.254     10.240.1.103     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.240.1.253     10.240.1.103     25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion which is enabled in the `SETLOCAL` command at the top, otherwise the parser evaluates the entire contents of the `FOR` loop when it starts instead of on each iteration.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set found=false
set wip=10.240
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('route print ^| find " 0.0.0.0"') do (

    @echo on
    REM set localIp=%%i
    set ip=%%i
    set xwip=!ip:~0,6!

    IF "%wip%" == "!xwip!" (

        echo My IP:  !ip!
        route ADD 95.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 !ip!
        route ADD 54.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 !ip!

        set found=true
        goto :break
    )
)

:break
IF "%found%"=="true" (
    ECHO Found it.
) ELSE (
    ECHO Didn't find it.
)

ENDLOCAL
```

In the update above, note how variables which need to be evaluated on each iteration are wrapped in `!`. This is the notation for delayed expansion. If they are left in `%` then they would only be evaulated when the loop starts and would not be updated on each iteration.

Comment: It seems to have worked, but when I try to debug using echo on the variables are showing explicitly as thy're written in the batch. Ex: `set xwip=!ip:~0,5!`, `IF "10.25" == "!xwip!" (`, ` My IP:  !ip!`

Comment: @Rick - If you have the `@echo on` then you will see the command the parser _is going to evaluate_ printed on the screen. This includes the `!` notation because it has not been evaluated yet (due to the delayed expansion). The output should be correct though. As a side note, you are missing a closing `)` on your `IF` statement which I updated above.

Comment: Ok got it. I am trying to add a found flag. Given the ! notation, if I place it within the if as `set found="true"`, if I make a comparrison right after :break, would it be: `if "%found%" == "false"`?

Comment: @Rick - I updated the answer to show how to use a `found` flag variable.

Comment: Had to remove the quotes in the last if, but worked. `if %found% == true (`